# IF and ELSE statement issue

Tags: c#, if-statement

apologies for the vague title, I'm having a few issues with if statements in my program, this is not the exact code but should still outline my issues, in my program I have this:

```
if(entry.Contains("a"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("a");
}

if(entry.Contains("b"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("b");
}

if(entry.Contains("c"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("c");
}

else
{
    Console.WriteLine("d");
}
```

So my issue is, if I was to type a or b(the first two if statements), the else statement would still occur but if I was to type c, the else statement would not occur but I want it to act so that if i type a, b or c the else statement would not occur.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please pick up a book. This is an extremely basic part of the core language, both for C and for C#, and questions about the basic workings of a language are generally not suitable for Stack Overflow. There are *many* better resources for learning languages elsewhere.

Comment: It is pretty basic but we can always help Kerrek. Anjola, use if, else if and else.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want

```
if(entry.Contains("a"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("a");
}
else if(entry.Contains("b"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("b");
}
else if(entry.Contains("c"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("c");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("d");
}
```

Additionally, if you are using all the same variable types (i.e. `string` or `int`) you can also use a `case statement`. It does the exact same thing, it's just a bit neater:

```
switch(stringName)
{
    case "a":
        Console.Writeline("a");
        break;
    case "b":
        Console.Writeline("b");
        break;
    case "c":
        Console.Writeline("c");
        break;
    case "d":
        Console.Writeline("d");
        break;
    default:
        Console.Writeline("none of the above");
        break;
}
```

I don't think it'll work with `entry.Contains()` though.